# Using shared file templates in WebStorm

Tags: configuration, ide, webstorm

File templates for [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) can be placed in the `config/fileTemplates` directory of the local WebStorm settings folder.

In addition to the templates stored there, I have a couple of file templates for our project that are in the project SVN repository. I want WebStorm to also offer me these templates.

**Is there a way to tell WebStorm to use a specific folder in my working copy *on top of* the usual `fileTemplates` directory?**

I could find some hints, but they appear to be dead-ends (or maybe I'm missing something):

- The documentation on [sharing templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/sharing-live-templates.html) makes this sound very manual (as in, moving files around). This is not a viable approach, as the template files might be updated any time. I do not want to preemptively copy the files around after each of my daily working copy updates, just in case on of them has changed (nor do I want to watch out for changes to the templates folder - I want WebStorm to catch up on these udpates on its own).
- The article on [file and code templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/file-and-code-templates.html#scheme) refers to per-project templates that "can be shared among the team members". This sounds like the right thing, except that they have to be placed in the `.idea` folder (the folder with the project file(s)). As I'm working on a huge project with many submodules, each team member (of several dozen devs) is only interested in a different subset of the overall project, so everyone has their own `.idea` folder that is *not* committed to version control.
- The article on [project and IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/project-and-ide-settings.html) indicates that (only?) "Locations of the config, system, plugins directories can be modified in idea.properties file."

Comment: 1) is irrelevant as it refers to Live Templates rather than File Templates. File templates can be loaded from either IDE config directory or project .idea folder. There is no way to use arbitrary folder as a template storage. You can commit `.idea | fileTemplates` folder to VC to share it with your co-workers

Comment: @lena: A problem with the `.idea | fileTemplates` folder is that apparently, the submenu for new items will show only the global templates *or* the project templates, not the union of both.

Comment: so, you are looking for a possibility to merge templates from different locations rather than loading them from custom location?

Comment: @lena: I am looking for loading the templates from a custom location, without losing direct access to the templates loaded from the standard locations.

Comment: neither of this is possible